# MySQL select values based on a sub query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables , Table #1 => tbl_notification_flow has the  following information :

```
app_status
Booked
Notified
Missed
Defaulted
```

With the  app_status being the column name and Table #2 => tbl_appointment  has the following information :

```
id  app_status
1   Booked
3   Missed
4   Missed
5   Missed
6   Missed
7   Booked
8   Booked
9   Booked
10  Booked
11  Booked
12  Booked
13  Booked
14  Booked
15  Booked
17  Booked
18  Booked
19  Booked
20  Defaulted
21  Notified
```

With id and app_status being the  columns ,

I want to get a count of all the  app_status based on the  number of times they have appeared on Table #2 ,

I tried the  following query :

```
SELECT COUNT(tbl_appointment.id)AS total_count, tbl_appointment.`app_status`
  FROM tbl_appointment
 WHERE (tbl_appointment.`app_status`) IN
 (
   SELECT tbl_notification_flow.`notification_type` AS app_status 
     FROM tbl_notification_flow 
    WHERE tbl_notification_flow.notification_type != 'Other'
 )
```

It gets the following result :

```
total_count app_status
19  Booked
```

Please help with the  best query to get the  right results.

Comment: Your description doesn't talk about a `notification_type` column... in `tbl_notification_flow`. Yet you have it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  t2.app_status,
  count(*) as status_count
from 
  tbl_appointment t2 
INNER JOIN 
  tbl_notification_flow t1 ON t1.notification_type = t2.app_status
WHERE t1.notification_type != 'Other'

group by t2.app_status ;
```

with result:

```
Booked      13
Defaulted   1
Missed      4
Notified    1
```

Comment: @ypercube - thank You, in this case need change and t2.app_status - I create query based on screenshots, but Dindi include alias in it